# set cover where only certain special subsets are allowed

Tags: dynamic-programming, approximation, sets, greedy-algorithms, set-cover

I am trying to solve a problem which turns out to be a form of the set cover problem. I've implemented the greedy Set cover approximation algorithm for set cover, but it turns out to not be accurate enough for my needs.

Specifically I have a fixed, finite, list of special sets and I am trying to create a function which when given a set returns the smallest list of special sets which cover that given set, and that list should contain no sets which contain elements not in that given set. The fixed list seems like it should make the problem easier to solve than set cover, but I'm not sure how the additional requirement of no extra elements affects the difficulty. My sets also have a known maximum size which should also make this easier to solve.

A toy version of the problem is as follows:

> Let $U$ be the set $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$. All the sets we mention from
>   here on will be subsets of this set.
>
> Let $S$ be a list of special sets. For this version of the problem we
>   can use the following list:
>
> $$ S = [\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}, \{a,b,c,d\}, \{e,f,g,h\}, \{a,e\}, \{b,f\}, \{c,g\}, \{d,h\}, \{a,b\}, \{b,c\}, \{c,d\}, \{d,e\}, \{e,f\}, \{f,g\},\{g,h\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{d\}, \{e\}, \{f\}, \{g\}, \{h\}]$$
>
> For a given set $G$ what is the smallest list of sets which are part
>   of $S$ which cover $G$, (that is where the union of the sets in the
>   list is $G$).

For the above toy problem, the greedy approximation I've implemented, if presented with a set like $\{b, c, g, h\}$, produces $[\{c, g\}, \{b\}, \{h\}]$ instead of the smaller list $[\{b, c\}, \{g, h\}]$.

Has this sort of problem been well studied? Is there a known non-approximate algorithm given the additional constraints, that would be better than naive dynamic programming? A well-known name for the version of set cover where extra elements are not allowed would also be useful.

Comment: $[\{b, c\}, \{g, h\}]$? Is $\{b, c\}$ an element in $S$?

Comment: "which cover a given set" should be "each of which is a subset of a given set and all of which cover the given set".

Comment: @Apass.Jack Regarding $\{b,c\}$, yes it should be. I have amended the definition of $S$. Regarding your suggested rewording, I think my sentence was unclear since what you've suggested does not sound like what I meant. I've reworded it now. Does it sound correct to you now?

Comment: Then to cover $\{b, c, g, h\}$, just one set is needed, $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I don't want solutions that contain elements that are not in $G$ to be valid solutions. I've amended the question again. Thanks for making me state my question clearer!

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to the Set Cover problem, in the following sense.  (i) Given a collection S of sets over universe U, Set Cover asks for the smallest collection of the sets whose union is U.  This is a special case of your problem where the "query" G is U.  (ii) Conversely, given a collection S of sets over universe U and a "query" set G, finding a smallest sub-collection of S whose union is exactly G is equivalent to the set cover problem obtained by deleting from S every set that contains any element not in U.  OTOH, for "fixed" S and U, the problem has an O(|G|)-time alg.

Comment: @NealYoung An O(|G|)-time algorithm for this sounds great. Can you direct me to enough information to implement it for a particular fixed $S$ and $U$? Or is there just some non-constructive proof that such an algorithm exists?

Comment: Precompute the answer for every subset G of U.  The total run time for the pre-computation is exponential in |U|, but since U is fixed, |U| is constant, so the time for the pre-computation is constant.  Once you've done this, for a given G, just check in O(|G|) time whether G is a subset of U, and if it is, return the precomputed answer.   Probably not what you want, but your problem is equivalent to set cover as I mention, so there isn't much you could do that is better, barring special structure in your sets S.

Comment: @NealYoung Ah, of course. You’re right that I can’t use that technique directly since in the real problem |U| is too large to precompute all the answers. However, I think I might be able to exploit structure in the S sets to know which approximations from the greedy algorithm are insufficiently accurate and precompute those, which hopefully reduces the set of answers that need to be precomputed to a practical size. Worst case, precomputing certain common cases may increase perceived accuracy sufficiently. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is hardly easier than the general set cover problem.

Given a set $G=\{b, c, g, h\}$, we remove all elements in $S$ that are not contained in $G$, obtaining a collection of set $C=[\{c,g\}, \{b,c\}, \{g,h\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{g\}, \{h\}]$. Now the problem becomes the standard [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) with $G$ being the universe and a collection of 7 subsets. Since this reduction process takes $O(n^2)$ time where $n$ is the total number of elements in $U$, your problem cannot not significant easier than the general set cover problem unless there are further conditions to be exploited.

Unfortunately, the general set cover problem is NP-hard. It is one of [Karp's 21 NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems). Even more unfortunately, [the simple greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) achieves about the best approximation ratio, $H(s')$, where $S'$ is the maximum cardinality of the sets. Here $H(n)$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

If you have to obtain the exact minimum set cover, you will have to resort to exponential algorithms. One simple simplification that can be done is to remove all elements in $C$ that are subsets of another element of $C$. That is, we can replace $C$ by $[\{c,g\}, \{b,c\}, \{g,h\}]$. A simple brute force algorithm is just to test all subsets of $C$ of size 1, those of size 2, those of size 3, etc. A common way to attack the problem is by [integer linear programming](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Studies/T-79.7001/2008SPR/slides/hakala_080310.pdf).

Just in case, you might want to take a look at some literature on the set cover problems. For example, [An Exact Algorithm for Unicost Set Covering](https://www.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/user/demir/papers/An%20Exact%20Algorithm%20for%20Unicost%20Set%20Covering.pdf) and [LP techniques for set cover](http://www.nissanchair.com/pubs/A24_ICKEDS06017d.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to solve a problem that is some how similar to the set cover problem and would like to share my thoughts. What about trying an SMT solver or CSP solver?. However, I don't know yet if one of them would give better results

Comment: I’m attempting to solve this problem as part of another program, and I’d rather not add a general purpose solver as a dependency. ... But since I only need to solve the problem for one particular special list of sets, I might be able to get one of those solvers to produce a combat lookup table for me. I’ll look into that if no one else has a better suggestion.